# Having problems getting the button clicked value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have the following view:

```
@using SuburbanCustPortal.SuburbanService

<br />
<br />
<table>

      @if (ViewData["CustomerData"] != null)
       {
         foreach (var usr in (IEnumerable<CustomerData>) ViewData["CustomerData"])
         {

           using (Html.BeginForm("ShowCustomer2", "Customer", FormMethod.Post))
           {
             <tr>              
               @Html.HiddenFor(model => @usr.AccountId)

               <td>
                 <input id="btn" type="submit" value="View"/>               
               </td>

               <td>
                 @usr.Branch-@usr.AccountNumber
               </td>

               <td>
                 @usr.Name
               </td>

               <td>
                 @usr.DeliveryStreet
               </td>

             </tr>            

           }
         }
       }

</table>
<br />
```

I'd like to get the AccountId of the button clicked. It lists all of the accounts that are on that login.

I'm getting null no matter how I reference it:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ShowCustomer2(FormCollection formCollection)
{

  var corpid = MiscClasses.GetCookieInfo.TokenId;
  var acctid = formCollection.Get("AccountId");
  MiscClasses.GetCookieInfo.CurrentAccountGuid = acctid;

  var sb = new StringBuilder();
  sb.AppendLine("SuburbanCustPortal,Controllers.CustomerController.ExistingAccounts");
  sb.AppendLine(string.Format("corpid: {0}", corpid));
  sb.AppendLine(string.Format("acctid: {0}", acctid));
  Logging.LogInfo(sb.ToString(), _asName);

  var cr = new CustomerRequest();
  cr.CompanyId = corpid;
  cr.Account = acctid;

  return View("AccountScreen", _client.GetCustomerByGuid(cr));
}
```

Anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

I made the following change in the view:

```
@Html.Hidden(@usr.AccountId)
```

and as:

```
@Html.Hidden(usr.AccountId)
```

I added the lines just to verify the controller code:

```
var acctid = formCollection["AccountId"];
acctid = formCollection.Get("AccountId");
```

Both are still coming out as null.

Comment: Did you try var id = formCollection["AccountId"];

Comment: yes, actually I did, prior to changing it to .get. Same result 'null'.

Comment: I think it may be because you're using HiddenFor, which requires a strongly typed view.  
Either strongly type your view to your model or use the Html.Hidden() helper method instead.

Comment: check my modifications, am I doing it correctly?

Comment: I see you got your answer, but just to clarify, the correct overload of Html.Hidden in your case would be @Html.Hidden("AccountId", usr.AccountId).  Which will essentially produce the HTML in Behnam's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are using property of a class called `CustomerData`.it will produce `CustomerData.AccountId` for your hidden field `name` attribute.try rendering hidden tag manually like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="AccountId" value="@usr.AccountId">
```

Answer (score 0):

you are binding wrong the hidden field name

try:

```
@Html.Hidden("AccountId")
```

also in method post in server you can try

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ShowCustomer2(int accountId, FormCollection formCollection)
```